# Grammatikalische Korrektheit von »was ich von der eurigen Arbeitsstelle erwarte«

Tags: grammar, formality, possessive-pronoun

In einer Bewerbung möchte ich schreiben:

> Das ist, im Grunde genommen, was ich von der eurigen Arbeitsstelle erwarte.

Ist dies grammatikalisch wohlgebildet? Dazu muss ich auch fragen, ob es vielleicht auch ein wenig veraltet klingt.

> Das ist, im Grunde genommen, was ich von eurer Arbeitsstelle erwarte.

scheint korrekter zu sein, aber nicht schöner.

Comment: Darf ich angesichts des Sprachstils raten, dass Du frisch aus der Schule kommst, vermutlich aus einem Gymnasium?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Das muss dann aber ein sehr humanistisches Gymnasium sein. Wahrscheinlich eins, wo man erst Altgriechisch und dann Latein lernt.

Comment: Nicht notwendigerweise. Ich hatte in den letzten jahren die zweifelhafte Ehre, diverse Texte frischer Abiturienten zu korrigieren und ein bedeutender Anteil hatte einen derartigen Stil. Es ist sehr unwahrscheinlich, dass die alle einer solchen Schule entstammen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Natürlich darfst du fragen! Es sind zwei Jahre her, seit meinem Abitur, aber eigentlich spreche ich Deutsch als dritte Sprache. Meine Muttersprache ist Spanisch aber ich habe in den letzten Monaten fast ausschliesslich alte Romane aus der Romantik gelesen, wobei es möglich ist, dass mein Stil ein bisschen komisch wirkt.

Comment: Latein-induziert wäre wohl "von dieser Eurer Arbeitsstelle". Tönt gestelzt und aufgesetzt und dient höchstens als Erkennungszeichen Verbildeter ;)

Comment: "euerig" ist veraltet.  Ich weiß nicht, wann mir das das letzte Mal begegnet ist.

Comment: Side comment: "erwarte" klingt etwas hart, vielleicht lieber "erhoffe"? Am besten eine neue Frage dazu erstellen! ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Ich rate dringend davon ab, *von der eurigen Arbeitsstelle* irgendwo und speziell in einem aktuellen Bewerbungsschreiben zu verwenden. *Eurig* wird als Fürwort verwendet, nicht adjektivisch:

> Wir haben unsere Autos verglichen, das unsrige ist besser als das eurige.

Somit ist *von der eurigen Arbeitsstelle* falsch; man würde natürlich verstehen, was gemeint ist, doch der Eindruck wäre eher ungünstig.

Es muss auf jeden Fall heißen:

> Das ist **es** im Grunde genommen, was ich (mir) von eurer Arbeitsstelle erwarte.

Das *es* muss hier als Platzhalter für den Nebensatz eingesetzt werden. Das *mir* ist ein Zusatz, der nicht unbedingt sein muss, der aber klärt, dass es um deine persönliche Vorstellung von diesem Arbeitsplatz geht; »ich erwarte von …, dass …« könnte einen Befehlston implizieren, der in einer Bewerbung unpassend ist.

Aber noch drei Fragen bzw. Bemerkungen dazu:

1. Bist du mit (Personal)chef oder -chefin per Du? Falls nicht, empfiehlt sich stattdessen in einem Bewerbungsschreiben das *Sie,* es sei denn, das Unternehmen hat explizit für alle die Du-Form eingeführt (wie z. B. vermutlich Ikea).
2. Es geht natürlich um eine Arbeitsstelle, die von dieser Firma angeboten wird, und damit um »eure Arbeitsstelle«, aber genauso um eine, von der du möchtest, dass sie in Zukunft deine Stelle ist. Außerdem willst du hier ja deine Vorstellungen vermitteln. Ich würde also eher schreiben:

   > … was ich mir von meiner zukünftigen Arbeitsstelle erwarte.

Aufgrund der Einwände in den Kommentaren möchte ich präzisieren: Diese Formulierung bezieht sich auf grundlegende Eigenschaften, die du von jeder Arbeitsstelle erwartest. Wenn du dich nur oder vor allem auf die Stelle beziehen willst, für die du dich bewirbst, ist es besser, zu schreiben:

> … was ich mir von dieser Arbeitsstelle erwarte.

3. *im Grunde genommen* wirkt hier auf mich etwas unentschlossen, ähnlich wie *eigentlich.* Man könnte stattdessen schreiben:

   > Das ist es grundsätzlich, was ich mir von meiner zukünftigen / von dieser Arbeitsstelle erwarte.

Es ist kaum möglich, aus einem einzigen Satz den Kontext zu erraten – leider machen viele Fragesteller hier diesen Fehler, immer nur den kleinstmöglichen Schnipsel zu präsentieren ohne Chance, einen größeren Zusammenhang zu erkennen –, aber warum setzt du diese Aussage nicht an den Anfang dieses Gedankens:

> Ich erwarte mir von dieser Arbeitsstelle, dass …

Comment: In dem Beispielsatz empfinde ich das "es" als möglich, aber mitnichten notwendig.

Comment: "...was ich mir von meiner zukünftigen Arbeitsstelle erwarte." - falls die Aussage nicht allgemein gemeint ist ("... was ich generell von meinen Arbeitsstellen erwarte ..."), sondern sich konkret auf die Arbeitsstelle, um die es in der Bewerbung geht, bezieht, wäre das aber eine extrem ungünstige Formulierung. Ich würde das als äußerst anmaßend empfinden, wenn ein Bewerber eine angebotene Stelle schon mal vorsorglich sprachlich in Anspruch nehmen würde, bevor überhaupt eine Zusage da ist.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper Wenn es um grundsätzliche Kriterien geht, wechseln diese ja nicht mit der angebotenen Stelle, und es ist durchaus eine positive Eigenschaft, klar zu sagen, unter welchen Umständen man am besten seine Leistung bringen kann.

Comment: @MartinSchwehla: Genau; meine Bedenken beziehen sich nur auf den Fall, dass der Bewerber konkret die angebotene Stelle meint (was zumindest auf Grundlage der ursprünglichen Formulierung, "eurer Arbeitsstelle", durchaus der Fall sein könnte).

Comment: Ich gehe davon aus, dass allen Beteiligten klar ist, um welche Abeitsstelle es geht. Daher würde ich `diese Arbeitsstelle` verwenden.

Comment: Selbst, wenn nicht klar ist, um welche Arbeitsstelle es sich handelt, wird das durch `eure Arbeitsstelle` nicht besser. Der Grund für `diese` statt `eure` Arbeitsstelle ist, dass ein Personaler wohl kaum für Arbeitsstellen *anderer* Firmen verantwortlich ist. Und wenn unklar ist, um welche Arbeitsstelle es sich handelt (weil es eine Initiativbewerbung ist oder mehrere Stellen ausgeschrieben sind), dann sollte es `eine Arbeitsstelle bei Ihnen/euch` sein.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Da er sich um diese Arbeitsstelle bewirbt bezieht sich das "erwarte" auch dann auf diese Stelle, wenn er nicht "meiner zukünftigen" schreibt. Wenn man zuviel in mögliche, spitzfindige Interpretationen hineinliest wird man nie eine Stelle vergeben. Wozu schreibt eine Firma eine Stelle aus, wenn sie sie nicht besetzen will?

Comment: @Martin Schwehla: Deine Antwort war genau was ich brauchte. Selbst wenn es kaum Kontext angegeben worden war, hast du alle impliziten Fragen beantwortet. Ich werde daher mit "Das ist es grundsätzlich, was ich mir von eine Arbeitsstelle bei Ihnen erwarte." bleiben. Danke sehr!

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: Ich verstehe was du meinst und ich würde normalerweise länger darüber nachdenken, ob dieser Satz den richtigen Ausdruck überträgt. Es handelt sich aber um eine Firma, die einen solchen Paragraf über persönliche Erwartungen fordert.

Comment: @ChristianSosa OK, freut mich, aber vergiss bitte nicht das "r" in "einer" ;-)

Comment: @userunknown: Finde ich nicht, die Erwartung kann sich entweder speziell auf die Stelle, um die es gerade geht, beziehen ("Wenn ich bei dieser Firma arbeite, erwarte ich ..."), oder generell für alle Arbeitsstellen gelten ("Ich möchte generell nur Arbeitsplätze, an denen ..."). Im letzteren Fall ist die Ausdrucksweise "meine Arbeitsstelle" sicher gerechtfertigt (dass man irgendwo eine Arbeit findet, ist i.A. sicher keine zu weitgehende Annahme), im ersteren Fall klingt sie aber eben sehr anmaßend, weil man dadurch andeutet, es sei schon sicher, dass man diese konkrete Stelle bekommt, und ...

Comment: ... somit dem Unternehmen quasi seine Entscheidungsfähigkeit abspricht. Das ist in ungefähr so, als würde man beim Vorstellungsgespräch schon darauf hinweisen, dass einem der Arbeitgeber übrigens demnächst schon Gehalt schuldet, oder dass man jetzt gerne seinen Schreibtisch benutzen würde, obwohl man noch gar keine Zusage hat, die Stelle überhaupt zu bekommen.

Answer (score 0):

"euerig" kann man nicht für "euer" verwenden. Es kam vor 100 oder 200 Jahren nur in Briefschlüssen vor in der Form "der eurige" (Wörterbuchnetz). DWDS hat "euerig" nicht mehr.